# 100 prisoners riddle - Dependency of probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, puzzle

I am referring to the well-known riddle of the title (if you don't know what I am talking about here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem - See sections "Problem" and "Solutions"). It is a subject that has already been discussed a lot and I already get the most of it but here is what I don't fully understad "intuitively":

If we take the "naive" approach where every prisoner opens $50$ boxes randomly his probability of success is $1/2$ and is INDEPENDENT for every prisoner each time. With the optimal solution's approach (called "loop approach") I have read that the first prisoners's try still has a probability of $1/2$, but the next ones have a differnt probability because (as a lot of people have highlighted) they are not independent anymore. So what is this new DEPENDENT probability for the 2nd, 3rd, etc prisoners and to what exactly is it dependent to?

Comment: If the first prisoner fails, we know for sure that there exists a large cycle ($>50$) in the permutation, so there will be at least $50$ other prisoners who fail.  This is not a proof, because I haven't calculated the probabilities, but I think it gives some intuition.

Comment: I agree, but I am not sure how would it change the probability if the 1st prisoner succeded because this tells us that there is at least one small cycle (<50) but doesn't give any information about the existance or not of a large cycle.

Comment: But we know that all prisoners on the same cycle will either succeed or fail simultaneously. That's highly dependent.

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ are independent resp. dependent if and only if $\neg P$ and $Q$ are independent resp. dependent.

Comment: Ok, so would it be okay to claim that this loop approach "forces" prisoners of the same loop to check the same sequence of boxes, and if we only have small cycles we succed?

Comment: Sorry, I should add that this is indeed a proof.  If no cycle $>50$ exists, all prisoners succeed.  So whatever the probability of the existence of such a cycle, the first prisoner can bet on such a cycle not existing, and if it exists, that they are not included.  But after the first prisoner fails, the second one can *only* bet on not being included in the cycle (the first option is gone).  And to make it worse, the fact that the first prisoner was included, raises the expected length of such a cycle.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanations!

Comment: Note that dependency cannot change the probability for each prisoner.  With the loop strategy, the second prisoner still has a probability of $1/2$, as does the third, the fourth, etc.  The difference is that the probability that they all succeed is no longer the product of the individual probabilities.

Comment: Sounds obvious now but it slipped my mind, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If prisoner #1 succeeds by finding a cycle of length $n$, then:

1. The other $n-1$ prisoners in that cycle will all also succeed by making their way through the same cycle.
2. The prisoners *not* in that cycle may still be in a long cycle (and thus will fail when it is their turn) but it becomes gradually less likely: Instead of the probability of a cycle of length at least $50$ in a pool of $100$ items, it is now a cycle of length at least $50$ in a pool of $100 - n$ items.

A prisoner who succeeds but is not in any previously found cycle will similarly ensure that all other prisoners in the new cycle will succeed, and reduce the pool of items that remain to be permuted, and thus further reduce the likelihood that a long cycle exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think it was really on point!